# Index is created but I get Seq Scan

Tags: postgresql

**PostgreSQL 9.5.7**

I have created an index for username.

Now I do:

```
explain analyze select * from authentification_user where username='Pele';
```

And I get:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on authentification_user  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=1 width=478) (actual time=0.017..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: ((username)::text = 'Pele'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 19
 Planning time: 0.101 ms
 Execution time: 0.040 ms
(5 rows)
```

**The problem is: why it is a Seq Scan? It is supposed to be an Index Scan.** Could you give me a kick here?

```
simple_project=# \d authentification_user
                                  Table "public.authentification_user"
  Column  |          Type          |                             Modifiers                              
----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer                | not null default nextval('authentification_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 username | character varying(10)  | not null
 pw_hash  | character varying(100) | not null
 email    | character varying(100) | not null
Indexes:
    "authentification_user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "authentification_user_username_e9ac7af7" btree (username)
    "authentification_user_username_e9ac7af7_like" btree (username varchar_pattern_ops)

simple_project=#
```

Comment: Please read https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_my_queries_slow.3F_Why_don.27t_they_use_my_indexes.3F . In your case, you simply do not have enough data to be worth to run Index Scan.

Comment: Thank you. If you organize your comment as an answer, I could accept it gladly.

Comment: Added the comment into answer :)

Comment: For only 20 rows, a Seq Scan is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's good [Postgres Wiki page about Index vs Seq scan usage](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_my_queries_slow.3F_Why_don.27t_they_use_my_indexes.3F) explaining this.

In your case, simply there is not enough data to take any benefit of Index Scan.